# Get C# ArrayList into JavaScript Array

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am working on a asp.net project and facing a little problem which I unable to get proper example from google search.

In my project I have an ArrayList() named arrayList. I just want to get this arrayList in a JavaScript array.

My ArrayList is just like below code :

C# code :

```
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    arrayList.Add(1);
    arrayList.Add(2);
    arrayList.Add(3);
```

JavaScript Code :

```
    var jsArray = new Array();
```

Here I need to get c# whole arrayList into JavaScript array named 'jsArray' .

How can I get this?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you want to transfer this array list to JS method ? from codebehind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Asp.Net

You need to write the below code to return the array. I've alerted cars.length where you get your Array.

Step1 : Aspx Page

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#Button1').click(getCars);
        });

        function getCars() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetAllCars",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var cars = response.d;
                    alert(cars.length);
                },

                failure: function (msg) {
                    $('#output').text(msg);
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
```

Step 2: aspx.cs page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Collections;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


   [WebMethod]
   public static Array GetAllCars()
   {
      ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
      arrayList.Add(1);
      arrayList.Add(2);
      arrayList.Add(3);
      return arrayList.ToArray();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first convert the ArrayList to JSON, which is a format that both C# and JS understand:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(arrayList);
```

Then you need a way to transfer this JSON from the server to the frontend. there are 2 ways:

You put it in an empty element in your DOM (can be an input control, a div, anything), and you then read it out via the Javascript.

OR you create a web service endpoint on your server that you can access using your javascript.

A possible 3rd option is by using RegisterClientScript, but that requires you to build your javascript server side which can be really tricky and is not recommended for something this complicated.

The easiest method is the DOM, but it's also the slowest, since it requires DOM analysis, which can be really slow. It's also somewhat error prone.

The web service is a little harder to implement, but it's the faster of the 2 methods. It also means you can build your JSON on demand when your JS needs it, which results in less possible mistakes when your JS tries to access it when it's not yet there.

Anyway, once you received the JSON, you can use JSON.Parse() in your javascript code to convert the JSON to a javascript object.

Comment: Thanks bro for explanation, Now I am clear. :) @ Nate Kerkhofs

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft library to get the JSON string.As Below

**in c#.**

```
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    arrayList.Add(1);
    arrayList.Add(2);
    arrayList.Add(3);

    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer jsr = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
    System.IO.StringWriter sw=new System.IO.StringWriter();
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter jtw = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter(sw);
    jsr.Serialize(jtw, arrayList);

    string jsArrayJSON = sw.ToString();
```

Now pass that jsArrayJSON string to javascript with method as per your program flow.

**In Javascript use Jquery to get the javascript object.As below**

```
  var jsArray = jQuery.parseJSON(jsArrayJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For this you have to use Ajax call. 

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#Button1').click(getListofStudents);
        });

        function getListofStudents() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "Default.aspx/getListofStudents",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var  ListofStudents= response.d;
                    alert(ListofStudents.length);
                },

                failure: function (msg) {
                    $('#lblerror').text(msg);
                }
            });
        }

    </script>


And then on .cs file 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Collections;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


   [WebMethod]
   public static Array getListofStudents()
   {
      ArrayList  ListofStudents= new ArrayList();
      ListofStudents.Add("jhon");
      ListofStudents.Add("Shon");
      ListofStudents.Add("Mohan");
      return ListofStudents.ToArray();
   }

}


This is one of the best example of getting work from .cs file using Json Service.
```